# set WKInterfaceButton title color - WatchKit

Tags: ios, watchkit

Is there a way to change color of WatchKit WKInterfaceButton title programmatically? I know I can change it in storyboard but I need to change it in the code.

Per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceButton/setAttributedTitle:) it doesn't say whether such an action is allowed or not. I did try looking at all the available methods for WKInterfaceButton and there was one for setBackgroundColor but not for title color. Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you try something like `myButton.titleLabel?.tintColor = UIColor(...)`? Like we usually would?

Comment: yup tried but those methods are not found on WKInterfaceButton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to ColdLogic for pointing me in the right direction. Its a bit complicated way of changing title color but it works.

```
NSString *titleStr = @"Next";
NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titleStr];
[attString setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attString.string.length)];
//set color
[customBtn setAttributedTitle:attString];
```

Comment: You also need to #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried this, but it looks like you can use `setAttributedTitle:` and one of the attributes can be `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` with the color you want to set the title too.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift users, ready to use extension for **WKInterfaceButton**:

```
extension WKInterfaceButton {
func setTitleWithColor(title: String, color: UIColor) {
    let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)
    attString.setAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color], range: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
    self.setAttributedTitle(attString)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to set up your button to use a WKInterfaceGroup as its content, and insert label for your text.

[image]

Then you just setTextColor on the label

```
[[self myLabel] setTextColor:textColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Swift like the answer of @SamB :

```
let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "NewTitle")
attString.setAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], range: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))              
self.button.setAttributedTitle(attString)
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "NewTitle")
attString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(0, attString.length))
self.leftButton.setAttributedTitle(attString)
```

Answer (score -1):

Per the docs, you can set the title color in your storyboard: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/ (Table 1 – WatchKit button attributes)

Comment: i know, I need to change it programmatically.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I missed that part.